# Set CSS only menu disappear delay for submenus

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the sub menu items disappear after a certain amount of time using CSS only. Sadly if I have more than one sub menu and hover over the next sub menu the other one has not yet disappeared. Any way to make the previous sub menu disappear when the next sub menu is show with CSS only?

It wouldn't be hard for me to write a JQuery script to achieve this but would nice if I could do it using css. Would there be any JS/JQuery plugins to recommend if this is not possible with CSS?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBPBbj

```css
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block
}
nav > ul > li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s 1s;
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav li {
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
}
    
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Dropdown
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Dropdown
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as no one proposed a working CSS only solution apparently the only way to achieve this is through javascript/JQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/jkanckr3/

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Dropdown
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Dropdown
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```jQuery
var timeout;

$('nav > ul > li').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('nav > ul > li > ul').hide();
        $('ul', this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var self = this;
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('ul', self).hide();
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

```css
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block
}
nav > ul > li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
}
nav > ul > li:hover ul {
  //visibility: visible;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav li {
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a {
  display: block;

}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove transition: 0.2s 1s;

Comment: Like I said in my first sentence: "I'm trying to have the sub menu items disappear after a certain amount of time using CSS only."

Comment: It sounds like OP wants to maintain the delay but only if another sub menu isn't hovered over. @inControl, I'd highly recommend using JS/jQuery for this

Comment: I can't understand. You want them disappear after a certain amount of time. Now when you hover over the next sub menu the other one has not yet disappeared - as you want. I've read prev comment, seems like now I know what you want.

Comment: That's indeed what I mean, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the tarnsition time as shown below code.

```
nav > ul > li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105%;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/WoLoaX) example of code:

```
<ul id="mainNav">
<li>item 1
    <ul>
        <li>sub item 1</li>
        <li>sub item 2</li>
        <li>sub item 3</li>  
    </ul>        
</li>
<li>item 2
    <ul>
        <li>sub item 1</li>
        <li>sub item 2</li>
        <li>sub item 3</li>
        <li>sub item 4</li>  
    </ul>       
</li>
<li>item 3
    <ul>
        <li>sub item 1</li>
        <li>sub item 2</li>
    </ul>       
</li>
```

```
ul#mainNav {
float:left;
width:auto;
margin:0; padding:0;
color:white;
list-style-type:none;
}
ul#mainNav > li {
float:left;
display:inline;
position:relative;
padding:5px;
border:1px white solid;
background-color:black;

}
ul#mainNav > li:hover {
background:white;
color:black;
border:1px black solid;
}
ul#mainNav > li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}
ul#mainNav li ul {
position:absolute;
float:left;
width:100px;
height:0;
padding:10px;
margin:0;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition-property: opacity, visibility;
transition-duration: 1.4s, 0s;
transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}
ul#mainNav ul li {   
background-color:white;
border:1px black solid;
}
ul#mainNav ul li:hover {
background-color:black;
border:1px white solid;
color:white;

visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition-property: opacity, visibility;
transition-duration: 0s, 0s;
transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}
```

Comment: Still not it, the effect im trying to achieve is like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jkanckr3/